# Help with standard JS "Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript" loading automatically

Tags: visualforce

I have created a visualforce page in which the JS "Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript" is loading automatically. How to stop loading it. The version "3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript" is creating vulnerability. How to update the verion of it or stop loading it.Thanks.

Comment: What vulnerability are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

For the version to be updated, you would need to log a bug with Salesforce.

To remove this script entirely, do not use `rerender` on any element. This is what triggers the inclusion of this script.